# Prevent subdomain users from using Google webmaster tools

Tags: google-search-console

For special purposes, I offer subdomains to users.

I have Google Webmaster console access for my domain including all subdomains via domain property there.

However, I need to prevent my users from getting access to "their" subdomain via Google Webmaster tools. Currently, they can get access via customer1234.mydomain.com by using one of the methods that do not need DNS access such as HTML tag etc.

I do NOT want to prevent indexing (that would be easy). I just want to prevent them from getting access via the webmaster console.

Is there any way to prevent this?

I did not find anything,  *GPT does not know. Maybe there is an undocumented DNS entry or some setting in "my" webmaster console access?

Comment: If they have the subdomain, why shouldn't they be able to have Google webmaster tools for it?

Comment: As Stephen touched on, typically speaking web hosting services don't take any special measures to prevent users from accessing Google Search Console on subdomains delegated to them.